# Javascript, what if a parameter of a function is a function?

Tags: javascript

> Write a function called imageMap with the following type:
>
> ```
> imageMap(img: Image, func: (img: Image, x: number, y: number) => Pixel): Image
> ```
>
> The result must be a new image with the same
>   dimensions as img. The value of each pixel in
>   the new image, should be the result of
>   applying func to each pixel of img.
>   Your function will have use either
>   lib220.createImage or image.copy to
>   create a new image, or make a copy of the
>   original. Note that the fillColor parameter
>   for lib220.createImage needs to be a pixel
>   value. The figure on the right shows an
>   example output of using the imageMap
>   function as follows:
>
> ```
> let url = 'https://people.cs.umass.edu/~joydeepb/robot.jpg';
> let robot = lib220.loadImageFromURL(url);
> imageMap(robot, function(img, x, y) {
>   const c = img.getPixel(x, y);
>   return [c[0], 0, 0];
> }).show();
> ```

I know exactly what my assignment is asking but I have no idea how to handle a function has a parameter is a function. (I didn't upload the picture because I think it's unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Just check this:

```js
function do2and3(operation) {
  console.log(operation(2, 3));
}

do2and3((x, y) => x + y); // Add
do2and3((x, y) => x - y); // Reduct
do2and3((x, y) => x * y); // Multiply
do2and3((x, y) => x / y); // Divide

do2and3(function(x, y) {  // A more complex example
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
  return Math.pow(x, y);
})
```

Passing functions as parameters allow the main function to call it as if were a normal function, this give you the ability to extend something without modifying it.

The advantage of doing this is that you can "inject" functionality to an existing function without altering it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the starting point:

```
function imageMap(img, func) {
  // in here, make one or more calls to func. For example:
  const pixel5_5 = func(img, 5, 5);
}
```

Obviously calling the func with just 5,5 isn't going to solve the question, but it's an example of how you interact with a function that was passed in.

Comment: This is how I started as well, I create a copy of the image and modify the copy. I wrote double nested for loop and such like copy = func(copy , i ,j) in the loops but doesn't work. So specifically what should I do with func to get a correct result, any hints will be helpful, thanks

Comment: Please put your code in the question then. I was under the impression you didn't even know where to start.

Comment: I think I got it, the example that you provided helps me a lot, thank you so much.